# Why string.replace does replace only every second occurance?

Tags: java, replace

My code:

```
String newBody = response.body.replace(";\"\";", ";\"|||\";");
```

Where `response.body` is something like this:

```
"9.3";"";"";"";"";"";
```

After the execution it results into this:

```
"9.3";"|||";"";"|||";"";"|||";
```

Where I would expect this:

```
"9.3";"|||";"|||";"|||";"|||";"|||";
```

I assume it has something to do with the logic of the replacement, as I am taking this: `;"";` wanting it to be replaced by this: `;"|||";` while each replaced string is beginning of the new one. But I would still expect it to be handled...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid consuming the trailing `;` from each match but still check that it is there, use a regex with a look-ahead:

```
String newBody = response.body.replaceAll(";\"\"(?=;)", ";\"|||\"");
```

Comment: Yes, that's better :D. Btw here is proof that your regex works: https://regex101.com/r/hM0tK8/1

Answer (score 3):

In your example the `replace` method is looking for `;"";`. So it will find that starting at the first semicolon. However, after the first time, it then finds `""`, which it skips, and then finds that pattern again. It is because of your ending semicolon. What you should use is:

```
String newBody = response.body.replace(";\"\"", ";\"|||\"");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have assumed so. The only problem that I haven't used it was that it might happen I will have something like this `;""whateverHere;"";` which would cause issues.

Comment: @mattfred He still needs to use a regex with `g` modifier in order to globally replace, because that will only replace the first `;""`.

Comment: @lucasarruda This is a Java question, not a JavaScript question.

Answer (score 2):

Change this line :

```
String newBody = response.body.replace(";\"\";", ";\"|||\";");
```

To:

```
String newBody = response.body.replace(";\"\"", ";\"|||\"");
```